# Why is the nuclear fission of $U^{235}$ cross section by slow neutrons so large?

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

The fission cross section of $U^{235}$ by slow neutrons is huge, around 584barns = 58400 fm$^2$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235, however the geometrical cross section of a $U^{235}$ nucleus is actually small, assuming a radius of $7$fm, it is about 154fm$^2$ which corresponds to 1.5barn.

How is this possible ?  I admit comparing a measured cross sections to the geometrical one might be a bit naive,bu the nuclear interaction only has a range of several fm. The Broglie wave length certainly is rather large for slow neutrons, however, I consider this as a length scale perpendicular to the cross section. I don't consider it as a scale which tells us something how broad the wave front of the neutron is.

So what is the mechanism which makes the cross section so large (also compared to other nuclear processes)?

Comment: And what is the ‘size’ of a slow neutron? For example, calculate the de Broglie wavelength of a 26meV neutron. It takes two to tango in a cross section.

Comment: Now contemplate how the cross section for simple Coulomb scattering is infinite.

Comment: @Jon Custer: EM-interaction is of infinite range, whereas nuclear interaction is limited to 1-2fm.

Comment: Resonance may be?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed directly associate the equivalent wavelength of a neutron with its cross section. In *The Los Alamos Primer*, Richard Serber uses the analogy of shooting arrows at a target, where slowing down the arrow makes the target's diameter increase greatly.

Comment: Ok, I see, but why is it like this for $U^{235}$ and not for $U^{238}$ too?

Comment: @FredericThomas - in general, all neutron cross sections fall with energy until, for example, excited state resonances come into play. For 238U, the neutron has to supply energy to make the fission reaction go, so it has to be above a megaVolt. Your local ENDF mirror will show you a lot if data on all the various neutron induced reactions.

Comment: may be the answers to a similiar  question help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177486/why-u235-over-u238